# How to login user in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

I'm currently working on a Django project to get more familiar with Django. At the moment I'm trying to make two templates, one being the main page with a link to the login page, which will login the user and then return to the template and display additional content (will be handled through nginx) and another template that can only be accessed when logged in. For some reason, but don't seem to work or let's say the login doesn't work.

This is the views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def index(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html')

@login_required
def main(request):
    return render_to_response('loginrequired.html')
```

And this is the main template:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}

<html>
<head>
<title>Django NGINX Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Django NGINX Test</h1>
<img src="{{STATIC_PREFIX}}beach.jpg"/>
<BR><BR>
<h2>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="test">Log out</a> {{user.username}}
{% else %}
  <a href="login">Log in</a>
{% endif %}
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the login_required template:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}

<html>
<head>
<title>Django NGINX Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Django NGINX Test</h1>
<img src="{{STATIC_PREFIX}}beach.jpg"/>
<BR><BR>
Welcome {{user.username}}. You're now logged in as required.<BR><BR>
<h2>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="test">Log out</a> {{user.username}}
{% else %}
  <a href="login">Log in</a>
{% endif %}
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

And last, but not least my login template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Login</title>
</head>
<h1>User Login</h1>
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match.
        Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action="." >
{% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}</p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help. I have already studied the Django Tutorial for this, but I didn't get it.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What happens when you try to go to the login required page?

Comment: Well, when I try to access the login_required template it just shows it to me without asking for a login. I'm not sure, if I'm already logged in, but it doesn't display my username either or do I have to pass this to the view somehow?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure that you include the following middleware in your `settings.py`:

- SessionMiddleware
- AuthenticationMiddleware

To make sure a context variable named `user` is available to your templates, you need to make sure the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor is in your `settings.py`.

More info can be found in the [Djano auth topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests).

Comment: Seconding this answer: you're making things harder than they need to be if you're not using the forms and methods listed in the link above.

Comment: +1 for the reasons @Tom mentioned, and to add that you should use the [`render`](http://django.me/render) shortcut to make sure `RequestContext` is included.

Answer (score 1):

The user is logged in, but you're not passing it to the template, so it won't show the user details. Make sure your render your templates with a RequestContext, or use the new `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`.